# AWS Route 53 and response times

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, response, ping, amazon-route53

I want to use Route 53 with another provider (DigitalOcean) Does Route 53 add to the response time of my application?

I need Route 53 for the fail-over and health-check ability it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using an IP Address to connect to your site there will always be DNS lookups. Often multiple DNS lookups for every site you visit (and that's before you even start on the thirdparty lookups)

Also a DNS query is cached for the length of its TTL. So generally a client will only make a request at the start of the session, the time it takes will get lost in the rest of your application setup.

To get a sense of the scope of DNS, consider that you get 4 Billion DNS queries for $1 from Route 53. DNS queries are tiny, around 130 bytes, so they use negligible network traffic.

Since whatever you do you will need to send a DNS query across the internet (or your clients will) the only limiting factors with regards to response time will be the distance from your client of the DNS server and the servers response time.

Amazon have a DNS infrastructure that is well designed and sitting on top of a high performance global network. (of course there is little actual proof of that, for all we know, Route 53 could be run from a VM on someone's laptop - but it seems unlikely)

We can be reasonably sure that Amazon Route 53 is running on high performance hardware, and will be physically close to the end clients.

As for health checking that is done as a separate stream to the DNS queries, if Route 53 has queried a server to be alive it will keep that status for all incoming queries until the next status query.

## TL;DR

If you use Route 53, you are going to get response times comparable to any of the major DNS providers, purely because they can afford the scale and location that is required.

And since you can't actually do without DNS, you might as well go there!

Comment: Awesome. Exactly the answer i needed